# UITableview not reloading and refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

My problem is whenever the user taps a button, the `UITableviewcell` text colors needs to change. This is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath                                                                               *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(one == YES)
    {
        cell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.imageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.high.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.low.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    else if(two == YES)
    {
        cell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.imageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.high.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.low.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

I reloaded in the button action, but it's crashing when you reload.
I tried `[tableview setNeedsToDisplay];` still no use...

Comment: You've left out some very important info, such as what kind of error you get when it crashes, and what line it crashes on.

Comment: Nothing showing in console.. but the error is  0x121209b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi   - -- EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I'd suggest putting a breakpoint in your button action and  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to find out where the crash happens.

Comment: It crashes when we reload the tableview

Comment: sure they are bools. but how do u set them?

Comment: yeah... if button1 clicked BOOL one is YES...like that

Comment: so if no button is clicked, you cell wont me populated with any value.

Comment: it is showing the data in the cells friend..

Comment: If no button was pressed, it is showing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not returning a UITableViewCell.